# Shopify customers/account.liquid Create for loop sort of order

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to sort orders in customers/account.liquid by `shipping_address.name`

```
{% assign orders = customer.orders | sort: 'shipping_address.name' %}
{% for order in orders %}  
  <tr class="{% cycle 'odd', 'even' %} {% if order.cancelled %}cancelled_order{% endif %}">
    <td>{{ order.name | link_to: order.customer_url }}</td>
    <td><span class="ship_name">{{ order.shipping_address.name }}</span></td>
    <td><span class="note">{{ order.created_at | date: format: 'month_date_year' }}</span></td>
    <td><span class="status_{{ order.financial_status }}">{{ order.financial_status }}</span></td>
    <td><span class="status_{{ order.fulfillment_status }}">{{ order.fulfillment_status }}</span></td>
    <td><span class="total money">{{ order.total_price | money }}</span></td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

[see screen shot](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0233/9591/files/customer_account_order1.jpg?3844090010079794557)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use the sorted array! I made it easier to follow by renaming the variables a bit.

```
{% assign sortedOrders = customer.orders | sort: 'order.shipping_address.name' %}
{% for order in sortedOrders %}  
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

Hope you're getting enough sleep!

Comment: Your right on the syntax of the assign, I also had the attribute wrong in the filter. It works with other attributes like 'created_at" and 'order_number' but does not output content in the table when trying to sort by a sub-attribute "shipping_address.name"